# API Management notification parameters - where are they?

Tags: azure-api-management

I use the new APIM Developer Portal but when users receive email notifications, the URL mentioned in the email points to the legacy developer portal.
I can customize it but by default, the URL is filled out with a parameter named "$DevPortalUrl". I don't know where I can customize it to use the new developer portal URL instead of the legacy URL.
Is it somewhere in APIM?

Answer (score 0):

Use $DevPortalHost parameter this will navigate to the new developer portal. But this parameter is available in only few of the templates. May be in next release Microsoft might give that parameters in other templates as well

Comment: Do you know where I can find the list of these parameters?

Comment: open the template.. and you can find it to the right of the screen